# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to filter an array of items with a ion-searchbar, but my ts function gives me an error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase'

html code

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="function($event)"  showCancelButton="never"></ion-searchbar>
 <div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
  {{item.data.titre}} 
 </div>
```

typescript code

```
 itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
 items:Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit(){
      this.itemsCollection=this.fs.collection('Items', ref=>ref.orderBy('Timestamp', 'desc'));
      this.items=this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a=>{
            const data=a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return{ id, data};
          })
        }));
    }  

function(ev:any){
    this.ngOnInit();
    let val=ev.target.value
    if(val && val.trim()!=''){
    this.items = this.items.filter((item: any) => {
      return (item.titre.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
    }
  }
```

I can't fix it, thanks for helping me

Comment: The correct answer was already given, but just as a hint: don't type lambda parameters as any. Typescript will infer them for you and without any, you will see that item has no `toLowerCase` method. In that matter, try to get rid of all your anys - what's the point of using typescript if you strip it of proper typing? Also, don't name a function `function`. That's a reserved keyword and I'm surprised that even compiles.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
  {{item.data.titre}} 
 </div>
```

you have missed the `data` property of each object of items array.

It must be: -

```
this.items = this.items.filter((item: any) => {
      return (item.data.titre.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
```